# Retrieving Matrix Row data via Playa Relationship

Tags: matrix, playa, relationships

Apologies for the vagueness in the title.

I have two channels: **Businesses & Events**

I am trying to allow businesses to display special offers for any event. They choose the event in a Playa field and set the offer for that event in the same Matrix row. See the image for better clarity.

[image: Matrix with Playa]

On the actual event page, I'd like all child entries to be able to display the {title} of the business and the {offer} they provided in the row that the relationship was made.

I've tussled over this for the better part of the day with some (but not much) luck.

How would you approach this scenario, if this even possible?

Comment: Hey Wedodan - it's always good to show what code you've already tried.  Can you show the work you've done for templating for this?

Answer (score 2):

From what i understand - the example in the documentation is exactly what your referring to?
http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/celltype

Comment: Not exactly. That example's for pulling in Playa data from within the same entry. I need to: In {business_channel} entry matrix row_1 - column_1 set relationship to an {event_channel} entry. In column_2 set a {business_offer}. Then, in {event_channel} entry pull in in the entire row of data which would match row_1 - column_1's relationship. Which would be {business_name} &{business_offer}... if that makes sense. 

Long story short I need a way for a business to list an offer they are providing during a selected event, from within their {business_channel} entry (not the actual event entry).

Comment: OKay with you... The only way i can think of is by using parent tag, and a horrible if statement.
http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/templates#playa:parents

The idea being that we are in the event, we use that tag to get all the parent entry_ids. We then run a if statement against the matrix field -> playa cell to check which one has the ID that matches the event.

Might even need an embed too - which is less than ideal i know.

Comment: Yeah, thats where I'm at too. I've been using parent tags, but haven't quite gotten it working. I need to do some more experimenting, I know I can do it but it's lower on my list in the current build. Let you know how it goes!

Comment: How did you get it working in the end?